# Interlace Subequations Environments

Tags: amsmath, subequations

I wish to use the equations environment to obtain the following output:

```
Some text...
    a &= b  \\   (A.1a)
    c &= d       (A.2a)
and some more text...
    a' &= b' \\   (A.1b)
    c' &= d'      (A.2b)
```

I want to be able to tag (A.1) as `\label{eq1}` and (A.2) as `\label{eq2}`; that is, I want `\eqref{eq1}` to produce '(A.1)' and `\eqref{eq2}` to produce '(A.2)'. I am using `amsmath`.

If these equations were in a different order -- namely, if the middle two were swapped -- then this would be easy. I am struggling, however, to do it with the equations in the order above...

I can make these equations *individually* reference-able, by using things like `\addtocounter`, `\refstepcounter` and `\tag`, but only in a way that `\label{eq1a}` produces '(A.1a)'; I cannot do the 'combined' (A.1).

Comment: Are the equations in a single `align` or are they in separate `equation` environments?

Comment: They are in separate align environments. I've updated the question, hopefully in a clear way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this solution, the `mixedsubequations` environment can have as optional argument the labels for the various equations; let me call it *main*. If no optional argument is specified, the environment is *subordinate*.

In the main environment, the subequations counter is reset to 1, in order to produce “a”, in the subordinate environments it is stepped.

Note that this works only if the main environment and the subordinate ones all have the same number of equations (not necessarily in a single `align` environment each). Note also that the number of labels in the optional argument to the main environment is used to determine the number of equations.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{mixedsubequations}
\renewcommand{\themixedsubequations}{\alph{mixedsubequations}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_samt_mixedsubeq_int

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mixedsubequations}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \addtocounter{equation}{-\g_samt_mixedsubeq_int}
    \stepcounter{mixedsubequations}
   }
   {
    \int_gset:Nn \g_samt_mixedsubeq_int { \clist_count:n { #1 } }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \refstepcounter{equation}\label{##1}
     }
    \addtocounter{equation}{-\g_samt_mixedsubeq_int}
    \setcounter{mixedsubequations}{1}
   }
  \domixedsubequations
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\NewDocumentCommand{\domixedsubequations}{}
 {
  \cs_set:Npx \theequation
   {
    \exp_not:o { \theequation }
    \exp_not:n { \alph{mixedsubequations} }
   }
  \ignorespaces
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Title}

Some text
\begin{mixedsubequations}[eq1,eq2]
\begin{align}
a  &= b  \label{eq1a}\\
c  &= d  \label{eq2a}
\end{align}
\end{mixedsubequations}
Some more text
\begin{mixedsubequations}
\begin{align}
a' &= b' \label{eq1b}\\
c' &= d' \label{eq2b}
\end{align}
\end{mixedsubequations}

\eqref{eq1} \eqref{eq1a} \eqref{eq1b}

\eqref{eq2} \eqref{eq2a} \eqref{eq2b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I shall implement that tomorrow; assuming there are no mishaps, I'll accept the answer (already +1-d it!)

Comment: You are a latex machine! Works all fine. (I realised that 'tomorrow' was the weekend, and I didn't fancy working on the weekend. =P) My only comment, really, is that when I call `\eqref{eq1}`, it says that the label is missing; however, the label is printed as desired, so it's only very minor. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @SamT Doesn't happen to me.

Comment: That is strange. See [https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EHd7.png]. As I said, though, not really an issue. Thanks again for the code :)

Comment: @SamT It's not LaTeX saying the labels are missing, but TeXStudio, which can't see the related `\label` command which is hidden in the macros. I don't think there's much to do about it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ah yeah, sure, not a big issue. If I were doing loads of equations like this, then the autofill might be nice, but it'll only be a few.

Comment: You can fool TeXStudio in believing the labels have been defined by adding ``\catcode`\^^A=14`` (which makes the combination `^^A` into an alternate comment character) in the document preamble and inputting `\begin{mixedsubequations}[eq1,eq2]^^A\label{eq1}\label{eq2}`